# Creating a copy of a nested dictionary instead of a reference

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Why is it that using the `dict()` function does not create a copy with a nested dictionary as it does for a standard key:value pair dictionary?

Dictionary

```
A = {'key' : 'value'}
B = dict(A)
A['key'] = 10
print A, B
```

Output:

```
{'key': 10} {'key': 'value'}
```

Nested Dictionary:

```
A = {'key' : {'subkey' : 'value'}}
B = dict(A)
A['key']['subkey'] = 10
print A, B
```

Output:

```
{'key': {'subkey': 10}} {'key': {'subkey': 10}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to make a [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy
A = {'key' : {'subkey' : 'value'}}
B = deepcopy(A)
A['key']['subkey'] = 10
print(A, B)
# {'key': {'subkey': 10}} {'key': {'subkey': 'value'}}
```